# MYSQL CTE Recursive Update

Tags: mysql, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a MYSQL table which contain stock market data with Open, High, Low, Close (OHLC) at 5 minute intervals.  Using OHLC, I am interested in deriving 4 columns: Heikin Ashi Open, Heikin Ashi High, Heikin Ashi Low, Heikin Ashi Close.

The formulae for the 4 columns are as follows:

```
Heikin Ashi Close:  (Open+High+Low+Close)/4
Heikin Ashi Open:  [Heikin Ashi Open(Previous Row) + Heikin Ashi Close(Previous Row)]/2
Heikin Ashi High:  Max(High, Heikin Ashi Open, Heikin Ashi Close)
Heikin Ashi Low:  Min(High, Heikin Ashi Open, Heikin Ashi Close)
```

Deriving Heikin Ashi Close is straightforward.  However, Heikin Ashi Open is derived from the Heikin Ashi Open and Heikin Ashi Close of previous row.  Row #2 to be computed based on Row #1 Heikin Ashi Open and Heikin Ashi Close.  Row #3 to be computed based on Row #2 Heikin Ashi Open and Heikin Ashi Close and so on...

I assume this can be done using CTE Recursive feature of MYSQL, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Can you please help?

Here is the CREATE and INSERT statement of sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `heikin_ashi_temp1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `scrip_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `high` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `low` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `close` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ha_open` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ha_high` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ha_low` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `ha_close` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=256 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO `market`.`heikin_ashi_temp1`
(`id`,
`timestamp`,
`scrip_name`,
`open`,
`high`,
`low`,
`close`,
`ha_open`,
`ha_high`,
`ha_low`,
`ha_close`)
VALUES
(1,'2020-01-17 09:19:59','ACC20JANFUT',1507.2,1507.2,1499.65,1502.5,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(2,'2020-01-17 09:20:35','ACC20JANFUT',1502.5,1515.2,1502.5,1503.45,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(3,'2020-01-17 09:26:35','ACC20JANFUT',1514.65,1517,1511.1,1511.55,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(4,'2020-01-17 09:32:33','ACC20JANFUT',1514.05,1514.05,1510.6,1512,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(5,'2020-01-17 09:35:34','ACC20JANFUT',1512.45,1516,1510,1511.7,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(6,'2020-01-17 09:41:35','ACC20JANFUT',1516,1516,1512.1,1513.95,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(7,'2020-01-17 09:47:34','ACC20JANFUT',1513.35,1513.35,1511.6,1512,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(8,'2020-01-17 09:50:31','ACC20JANFUT',1511.7,1513.4,1510.4,1511.3,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(9,'2020-01-17 09:56:34','ACC20JANFUT',1513.4,1516.7,1513.15,1513.95,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(10,'2020-01-17 10:02:34','ACC20JANFUT',1516.15,1519,1514.15,1514.65,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(11,'2020-01-17 09:19:59','ADANIENT20JANFUT',217,217.05,215.35,215.5,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(12,'2020-01-17 09:20:35','ADANIENT20JANFUT',215.45,216,214.15,215.65,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(13,'2020-01-17 09:26:34','ADANIENT20JANFUT',215.5,217,214.75,215.8,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(14,'2020-01-17 09:32:33','ADANIENT20JANFUT',216.5,216.9,216,216.2,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(15,'2020-01-17 09:35:34','ADANIENT20JANFUT',216.85,217.65,216.5,217.4,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(16,'2020-01-17 09:41:35','ADANIENT20JANFUT',216.6,217.45,216.25,216.65,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(17,'2020-01-17 09:47:34','ADANIENT20JANFUT',217.4,218.65,217.3,217.7,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(18,'2020-01-17 09:50:31','ADANIENT20JANFUT',217.95,218.05,217.5,218.05,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(19,'2020-01-17 09:56:33','ADANIENT20JANFUT',217.65,217.65,217.45,217.5,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(20,'2020-01-17 10:02:34','ADANIENT20JANFUT',217.85,218.2,217.5,217.6,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check:

```sql
UPDATE heikin_ashi_temp t1
JOIN ( SELECT id,
              `timestamp`,
              open,
              high,
              low,
              close,
              CASE WHEN @open=0
                   THEN @open:=open
                   ELSE @open:=(@open+@close)/2
                   END AS ha_open,
              @close:=(Open+High+Low+Close)/4 AS ha_close
       FROM heikin_ashi_temp, (SELECT @close:=0, @open:=0) vars
       ORDER BY `timestamp` ) t2 USING (id)
SET t1.ha_open = t2.ha_open,
    t1.ha_close = t2.ha_close,
    t1.ha_high = GREATEST(t2.high, t2.ha_open, t2.ha_close),
    t1.ha_low = LEAST(t2.high, t2.ha_open, t2.ha_close);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b0b544fdfef37d70a0464a21b4b943f1)

PS. Pay attention - source data was changed, last 4 field values are cleared and then are recalculated "from zero".

Comment: thank you very much.  Appreciate it.  This solution worked for me.  On an another note, I got the following warning:  103 row(s) affected, 5 warning(s): 1287 Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.  Should I be worried with future releases?

Comment: @lenmet There is no point in worrying about this - direct assignment to variables will not be allowed for a long time. At least until version 9...

Comment: But when this happen - you're right, you should use recursive CTE for to iterate over the records, or use stored procedure with cursor.

Comment: Hi Akina, I ran into some trouble when I tried to expand the focus of this query to multiple scrip names.  I then realized I should have framed the original question with multiple scrips in the sample data.  Apologies on that.

Attached Insert statement has sample data for two scrip_name.  Id 1 to 10 is for one scrip and 11 to 20 is for another scrip.  At Id = 11, since it is beginning of a new scrip, 'ha_open' should be equal to 'open' instead of 'ha_open' being computed based on Id=10 (ha_open+ha_close)/2

Comment: I tried to modify the query by specifying the join condition as:  ON (t1.`id`=t2.`id` and t1.`scrip_name`=t2.`scrip_name`); however, this did not give me the desired result.  I believe the CASE statement has to be slightly modified.

I would appreciate if you can relook at this and help troubleshoot.

The CREATE and INSERT Statements are updated in the original post.

Comment: This is a different task, although it is similar to this one. Create new question. Refer to this question if you think it's useful.

Comment: To solve you need: add one more variable for to store previous scrip name, sort by scrip then by timestamp, check does the scrip name is changed. I think you can do it yourself...

Comment: @lenmet If you cannot look [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c798e8d7e1004b6fbde678cf3a0c54e0).

Comment: thank you so much Akina. Before I could think of a solution, you have provided the solution. This worked for me.

Just so that I understand it fully, can you please clarify what does (SELECT '@'close:=0, '@'open:=0, '@'scrip_name='') vars do.

Comment: @lenmet Non-initialized variable's value is NULL. When accessing. But it is only a start of problem. The problem is that plan builder may assume that a variable is NULL constantly! and it will replace the variable with NULL... So variable must be initialized by some value explicitly. The most common way to do it is to assign a value in SELECT - like in my query.